# If I attach the heat sink on the transistor, will switching power loss be lower?

Tags: transistors, heatsink

If I attach the heat sink on the transistor, will PWM switching power loss of transistor be lower?

Comment: Generally speaking, the power loss will be pretty much the same, but the temperature rise will be less.

Comment: Adding a heat sink isn't just a thermal change: The sink being conductive, expect stray capacitances to change. If there is an increase in distance between switch and driver, inductances increase, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The energy that is turned into heat is dependent on the voltage across the transistor and the current through it. As the transistor heats up, these values will change, but in which direction depends on the rest of the system.

Adding a heatsink changes how much heat will be transferred out of the transistor, and this change in temperature also has an effect on the internal resistance of the transistor -- again, the direction of the change is dependent on the rest of the system.

In *most* systems, a higher temperature in the transistor means that more power will be dissipated there while current is flowing, so the heatsink reduces this a little. The *switching* power loss, however, depends more on the time it takes for the channel to close, and whether the transistor can pinch off the current flow effectively.

Usually, the deciding factor for a heatsink will be that we roughly know how much power will be converted to heat, and then the effectiveness of the cooling solution (typically given in watts per degree temperature difference) tells us how much rise in temperature we can expect before the amount of heat added and the amount transported away are the same and we reach an equilibrium point. If that point is higher than acceptable (e.g. above the recommended operating conditions), we need a better cooling solution.

Comment: I saw related paper. https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/221398/221398.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwitn6y--4z8AhXgpVYBHWPCD0g4FBAWegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3LLQ3naqzglOMKWDjY6UAz

Comment: That paper said the higher temperature, the higher losses.

Comment: @AhnJinHo, for the *switching* losses, which are higher than the static losses, it depends on source, transistor and sink impedance. during the switch -- "optimum" power transfer from the source to the transistor happens while they are well matched.

Answer (score 2):

A heat sink, keeping the device cooler, will have little effect on switching losses, but higher temperature may result in lower conduction losses for a BJT. For a MOSFET, higher temperature will increase the RdsON and conduction losses will increase.

Switching losses will add to the heat generated, so a heat sink will allow operation at a higher frequency before safe temperature is exceeded.

Comment: IGBTs also have a negative temperature coefficient for their conduction losses (as they are effectively BJTs as far as the output side is concerned).